# regarding UnicodeDecodeError error while invoking model.fit in Keras

Tags: python, theano, keras

When running a Keras implementation with Theano as backend.  I got the following error message, which I really have no clue about possible reasons. Should you ever meet this kind of problem, or are able to share any insight, I will be really appreciated.

In the following, I mark two lines with dark black. The first line is related to the code which causes the problem. The second dark black line, at the bottom, looks like the error message.

Problem occurred during compilation with the command line below:
/usr/bin/g++ -shared -g -O3 -fno-math-errno -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-write-strings -march=core2 -mcx16 -msahf -maes -mpclmul -mpopcnt -mavx  **skip some details ....**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                            
  File "train.py", line 144, in <module>                                                      
    train_and_predict()                                                                       
  File "train.py", line 129, in train_and_predict 

model.fit(imgs_train, imgs_mask_train, batch_size=32, nb_epoch=20, verbose=1, shuffle=True,callbacks=[model_checkpoint])                                                               
  File "/user/theano/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Keras-1.0.3-py3.4.egg/keras/engine/training.py", line 1037, in fit     
  self._make_train_function()                                                               
  File "/user/theano/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Keras-1.0.3-py3.4.egg/keras/engine/training.py", line 670, in _make_train_function                                         
    **self._function_kwargs)                                                                  
  File "/user/theano/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Keras-1.0.3-py3.4.egg/keras/backend/theano_backend.py", line 528, in function                                              
    return Function(inputs, outputs, updates=updates, **kwargs)                               
  File "/user/theano/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Keras-1.0.3-py3.4.egg/keras/backend/theano_backend.py", line 514, in __init__                                              
    **kwargs)
```

**.... skip some details ...**

```
File "/user/theano/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Theano-0.8.2-py3.4.egg/theano/gof/cmodule.py", line 1142, in module_from_key
    module = lnk.compile_cmodule(location)
  File "/user/theano/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Theano-0.8.2-py3.4.egg/theano/gof/cc.py", line 1506, in compile_cmodule
    preargs=preargs)
  File "/user/theano/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Theano-0.8.2-py3.4.egg/theano/gof/cmodule.py", line 2183, in compile_str
    compile_stderr = decode(p_out[1])
  File "/user/theano/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Theano-0.8.2-py3.4.egg/theano/compat/__init__.py", line 42, in decode
    return x.decode()
```

**UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 0: invalid start byte**

Comment: Don't give the whole error log, it reduces the readability of the post. Its fine if you can highlight the main thing that is causing the error according to you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have modified the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the error is because there is some non-ascii character in the dataset that you are using and it can't be encoded/decoded. One simple way to avoid this error is to encode such strings with encode() function as (if a is the string with non-ascii character):

```
a.encode('utf-8')
```

If you are reading data from file, you can also set `encoding='utf8'` as parameter to avoid such issues.

Comment: Hi Wasi, thanks for the reply. Just more details, I test the same program with Tensorflow as backend. Looks like it was running. Secondly, the input data, imags_train and image_mask_train, are npy file. How to ensure they are encoded as 'utf-8'.

Comment: It totally makes sense if you are using something which depends on tensorflow and theano. You will get normal behavior from one but abnormal from the other. How are you opening and reading the file? Can you use - open(file, mode='r', encoding='utf8') - something like this?

Comment: I see. Let me try. Thanks.